# UIPanGestureRecognizer - Avoid moving two images simultaneously - Swift

Tags: swift, conflict, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a ViewController with 3 UIImageView with its images. I am using Pinch, Pan and Rotate gesture on all three images. While doing Pinch or Rotation i got two finger point with opt+mouse_click. There in the finger point, if two images are pointed with each finger point, both images are moving around.

I actually don't want that move(pan) while doing opt+mouse_click, just need to rotate or zoom the images with two finger points.

Help me to resolve, Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using the `requiredToFail`  delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to limit the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` 's finger that touch on screen to 1 to avoid it. Rotate or zoom will need 2 fingers.

More information from Apple's doc

> The maximum number of fingers that can be touching the view for this gesture to be recognized.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621208-maximumnumberoftouches

Comment: I understand the maximum number of fingers concept, but in my case each two fingers placed on each two images, so the maximum number of fingers is still 1 for each image which i cant able to resolve. 
I am trying to find the first imageview in which the finger is placed first, so that i can avoid the other image from moving